# Change fragment dynamic crash app

Tags: android, fragment

I am getting crazy. I want to replace one fragment with another fragment dynamically.

I define a mainLayout in activity like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/EstiloBase"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_dashboard"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The item i want to replace is the FrameLayout.

At the start the FrameLayout is raplce with this fragment and all its ok:

```
 FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.calendar1, caldroidFragment);
    t.commit();
```

Then, when i click in a button it will be replace by this:

```
 case R.id.cambiarVista:
                FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                t.replace(R.id.calendar1, new ListaEntrenamientos());
                t.addToBackStack(null);
                t.commit();
```

This fragment it define like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="tfg.marcos.coachtrain.views.fragments.ListaEntrenamientos">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

But when I click on that button, the app crashes and it does not show me any message.

What is my error? I try it a lot of times with other options but is the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Logcat should show a message

Comment: By the way, `DrawerLayout acts as a top-level container` (the documentation). And it has no orientation... Try doing that xml again

Comment: select `No Filters` in logcat and post your logcat.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.garcia.coachtrain, PID: 15490
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: tfg.marcos.coachtrain.views.DashBoardActivity@e5649cc must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
                                                                                   at tfg.marcos.coachtrain.views.fragments.ListaEntrenamientos.onAttach(ListaEntrenamientos.java:84)

Comment: this is my logcat

Answer (score 0):

The `FragmentManager` crashes because `calendar1` is a `FrameLayout` and not `fragment`. Either make both `calendar1` and `ListaEntrenamientos` `Views`, or make both of them `Fragments`. Either will work. I will recommend making them `Views` (`LinearLayout/FrameLayout`), and just changing the `Visibility` of one to `GONE` when you don't want it on the screen.